# R valuebox on top of each other

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want the text in this `valuebox` on top of each other and not side by side. Does anyone know how to fix this? You can see my code and an image below.

```
valueBox(value = "C: 7.07 A: 7.03 B: 6.82", "Durchschnittliche Bewertungen der Filiale", color = "yellow")
```

[image: Valuebox]

tried some layout codes but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like based on tags you're using shiny and shinydashboard. You won't be able to add unicode `\n` newline for this; instead, you can wrap your text in `HTML` and then use `<br>` tag for line breaks. If you need to dynamically render the text in your `valueBox`, you can use `paste`. Below is a complete example.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Value box example"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      valueBoxOutput("myValueBox")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myValueBox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = HTML("C: 7.07<br>A: 7.03<br>B: 6.82"), "Durchschnittliche Bewertungen der Filiale", color = "yellow"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Image**

[image: screen capture of shiny site with valueBox]